# import python statements not working when called from JS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm unable to run my Python code from node.js.

The following is the Python code I'd like to run:

```
from preprocessor import pad_vec_sequences, labels
from keras.models import load_model
import spacy
from preprocessor import nlp
import numpy as np
import sys
from dependency_tree import to_nltk_tree , to_spacy_desc

print('Hi')
```

This code runs successfully from terminal using `python demo.py` and all the libraries are installed.
I'm using python 3.5.

Now I'd like to call this code from JS using:

```
app.post( '/api/message', function(req, res) {

PythonShell.run('demo.py', {
    args: [req.body.input.text], pythonPath : '/usr/bin/python3'
}, function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
      return res.json({
      'input' : { 
          'text' : ''
              },
        'output': {
            'text': results //+
            //'<img src="http://localhost:8080/Finance/image1.jpg" class="imageclass">'
         }    
    })
});
```

});

In the code above, I've set the `pythonPath` option to python3.5, and thus the python shell started by node.js is python3.5. I would expect the Python code to return `Hi` to JS.

But this does not work. The JS does not receive any text from `demo.py`. If I remove all the `import` statements, the code works. On removing the `import` statements the Python code called successfully returns the `Hi`.

So it looks like the Python code when called from JS does not work because of the import statements. But the same Python code works when called from terminal. I have also ensured that both cases use python3.5.

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE:**

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

... outputs `/usr/bin/python3`. I have put this in the JS code for `pythonPath` but my code is still not working.

Comment: Is your `PYTHONPATH` the same as in your command line when you run python from the command line? If it differed, it could cause an `ImportError`. Don't ignore `err`, at least `console.log(err)`, it could tell you why this isn't working.

Comment: @DanD. The `PYTHONPATH` I've mentioned is the same as I get from `which python` .

Comment: @DanD. I have added `console.log(err)` and it just says there are no modules with those names

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is the environmental variable, the search path that Python uses to find its modules. Not the path to the Python interpreter which was rightly given as `pythonPath`. You can access it on the shell with `$PYTHONPATH` or in Node as `process.env.PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @DanD. So how do I find the correct `pythonPath` to write in javaScript?